# Highlighting modified cell

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I was trying to highlight a cell in a column which is modified from "a" to "b" (should exclude the changes from blank to "a") via macro. Can anyone help me?

```js
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim KeyCells As Range
Set KeyCells = Range("A:A")
If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
ActiveCell.Select
Application.Run ("color")
End If
End Sub

Sub color()
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .color = 255
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
End Sub
```

The above code highlights the cells below the edited cell also.

Comment: What have you done so far to try to solve this yourself? Do you have any code, have you done any research? This question right now looks like "please do this for me."

Comment: 1) "Highlight" a cell manually while recording a macro, then go and check out the code you need to highlight. 2) Then, go to the Sheet code, specifically in the event "Worksheet_Change", and add this code with your condtions (if value was a and now is b, etc.).

Comment: See [Conditional Formatting](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback guys i was not able to upload my codes before apology for the inconvenience caused. And i need macro only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
Dim ValBeforeChange As String

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    ValBeforeChange = Target.Value

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    

    If ValBeforeChange ="" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    IF ValBeforeChange <> Target.Value Then
    
    If Application.Intersect(Range("A:A"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    Application.Run("Color")    
    End If
  
    End If
    

End Sub
```

This code works well guys thank you all for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `SelectionChange` event to get the value *before* change, and then add your conditions like so.

Note if the workbook is opened with a cell selected in your target range, and you change the value without changing the selection first, this code will exit early as the value of `ValBeforeChange` will not have been set yet.

You can deal with that a couple of ways.  You can add something to the `Workbook_Open` event to run the `SelectionChange` routine *or* you can make the `ValBeforeChange` a global variable and set it initially in the `Workbook_Open` event, or you could refactor the highlighting code into a class with "before" and "after" properties, instantiate a class object on open and clean it up on close.

Here is how you would add the conditional check:

> modified from "a" to "b" (should exclude the changes from blank to
>   "a")

```
Dim ValBeforeChange as String

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target as Range)
    ValBeforeChange = Target.Value
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If Not Len(ValBeforeChange) > 0 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Value = ValBeforeChange Then Exit Sub
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Set KeyCells = Range("A:A")
    If Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Highlight Target
End Sub

Sub Highlight(ByRef Target as Range)
    With Target.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the code CBRF23. Its highlighting the cell below the cell which is modified. And i gave an example about a & b values, if the a & b value is a numeric or time value, is it enough if i change the string to integer in "Dim ValBeforeChange as String"

Comment: You can change the type of `ValBeforeChange` to whatever you need, and change your conditions accordingly.  If my answer solved your question, please click the little checkbox next to it.

Comment: Sorry CBRF23 its not working :(.

My intension is to highlight a cell in a column if the previous value has been edited, excluding blank cell got updated

Comment: Edited per your request. Try it now.

Comment: Getting error "Sub function not defined" and higlighting Length

Comment: Oh now its working but its not highlighting. if i updated a value in a cell in range. sometimes its highlighting the next active cell. Hence i removed the line " ActiveCell.Select", however its highlighting both edited and the next active cell. Im confused...

Comment: Well when I answered your original question I assumed the rest of your code was working... You're probably better off adding a range argument to the color routine and then passing the target range to it that way.

Comment: Note that the color sub is a little redundant, its code is the result of a recorded macro and most of the properties are default values. You could just use `Target.Interior.Color = 255`.

Comment: I wouldn't name the sub "color" in any case, see how it affects the casing of `.color` within the sub.

Comment: @CBRF23 Just to note that `Range(Target.Address)` is unnecessary, Target is already a Range. It doesn't really matter, but I would also put `Range("A:A")` directly in Intersects, getting rid of KeyCells.

Comment: @AndyG - you are correct, and your other suggestions are valid.  I did not do a full code review on the OPs code, just trying to help get it working.  I'll edit my answer to reflect the suggestions you've made :)

Comment: @AndyG - actually on second thought I left the macro recorded stuff in there since I don't know if the OP had a purpose for that (e.g remove formatting as well as changing color)

Comment: @CBRF23 Oops, sorry, I should have been comparing your code to the OPs! Perhaps my suggestions can just be left in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I don't want to add new answer. Because this answer is a small modification of [CBRF23](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4106771/cbrf23)'s answer. According to their comments, I decided to add new answer because I think that this question is not get the right answer.

What are new in my answer. Nothing more special. But I formatted the code and **I added a checking for blank value and remove highlight**.

Here, you can see the code different.

```
Dim ValBeforeChange As String

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    ValBeforeChange = Target.Value

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    If Not Len(ValBeforeChange) > 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Target.Value = ValBeforeChange Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Application.Intersect(Range("A:A"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Target.Value <> "" Then
        Highlight Target, vbRed
    Else
        Highlight Target, xlNone
    End If

End Sub

Sub Highlight(ByRef Target As Range, ByVal colorValue As Variant)

    With Target.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .color = colorValue
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Nicolas, could please explain me where/how the **Sub Highlight** function works. There is nothing get highlighted when i tried the above code.

Comment: It is just change the background color(Interior Color) of inputed `Target` to inputed background `colorValue`. That all. I think that you should need to debug the code in line by line for know the real error. Because, I tested this code before I posted it. It work well for me. It has no error. I think that error should be from others. Not from this one.